# Reported speech with no change in tense

Tags: reported-speech, tense-agreement

I am doing homework about this topic and I don't know how to turn these statements into reported speech:

1. Direct speech: The concert is cancelled.

- Julian said that the concert is cancelled.
  Or
- Julian said that the concert was cancelled.

2. Direct speech: I can't play baseball, I'm injured.

- Tom said that he can't play baseball, he is injured. Or
- Tom said that he couldn't play baseball, he was injured.

What would be the correct answer?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: All of these are correct, depending on context. (1a) "What is the status of the concert?" "Julian said that the concert is cancelled." (1b) "Will you go to the concert?" "No. Julian said that the concert was cancelled." (2a) "Tom said that he can't play baseball today--he is injured." (2b) "Tom said that he couldn't play baseball last year--he was injured."

Comment: Ohhh thank you, @filistinist! I was so confused, but now it's clear.